# React.js: After updating form, not able to get updated value (`componentWillReceive`) inside a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

We get a form from the server that we allow the user to edit and are using lodash `_.set(object, path, value)` to update parts of that form depending on what part of the form the user updates.

We are trying to get the current value by setting the state inside the component but getting this error;

```
Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops
```

Our function looks like;

```
onChange = ({ form }) => {
const { path, editKeyword } = this.props;
const inputValue = form[editKeyword];

let prevForm = this.props.form;

// update the object using
const updatedForm = _.set(prevForm, path, inputValue);

// action
this.props.setCurrentForm(updatedForm); };
```

We also tried the following with no luck:

```
onChange = ({ form }) => {
const { path, editKeyword } = this.props;
const inputValue = form[editKeyword];
console.log("input value ", inputValue);

let prevForm = this.props.form;

const updatedForm = _.set(prevForm, path, inputValue);

// when we try to update local state
this.setState({ form: updatedForm}) };
```

Has anyone had any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `onChange` function triggers when some form values changing. I don't know what function `setCurrentForm` does, but if it mutates data which is relevant to the form, we have infinite loop here.
User changed form text value, `onChange` triggers and runs `setCurrentForm` function. The last mutate form text value, and `onChange` function becomes triggered again. I think this is the problem.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, `setCurrentForm` is trying to set the updated form in state. We tried to use componentWillReceiveProps, but can't get the updated state back as a props. We tried putting our action in onChange function and it changes the state correctly when the user enters a value. But when we finish typing it return back to empty string value as it can't get updated state to the component as a props, and then the onChange function triggers the action once again because value of the input is empty.

Comment: Is there a way around this and to set the updated form in state so we can get it back without causing an infinite loop or the value to be set as empty?

Comment: Of course, try to separate current user input and its handling from state. Let form logic run inside itself and update form only when user submit it. I did the same yesterday: a form for adding an element with several input tags. But they aren't bound with state, they get their initial values as props and when user click submit my function onSave runs dispatch(action) to update the store. Here should be kind of a buffer between user input and state, otherwise loop is inevitable.

Comment: and update form only when user submit it.
===== I meant this, sorry:
and update STATE only when user submit FORM.

Comment: Thanks! apologize for late reply. We are trying to use onChange, instead of submit. We created a code sandbox; https://codesandbox.io/s/oo3qknl296

Our requirement is that we will receive initial state of formData from the server, and we need to update a specific part of it using the path only (e.g. `task[0].title` or `task.title` like it would be in the example). We achieved that functionality and put it in onChange function as you can see in the sandbox. However, If we uncomment where we are trying to set the updated state, we see the error ```Maximum update depth exceeded...```

Comment: UPD:tip to understand:  when you reload the sandbox, look at the console. The next string after "Console was cleared" goes string "input value  
undefined", - this is the console.log output from onChange handler. So, as we can see, onChange gets triggered by react before user interacts with the form. React transmited state to component, and triggered onChange event. Put state change inside onChange and our loop will look like: redux ->react->component->form->onChange-> STATE CHANGES -> redux -> react ... - now you know what goes next :-)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this and the clarification of the loop! The remaining challenge for us is that we use `onChange` to trigger an auto-saving function of the updated form. Is there a way to still use onChange while avoiding this loop? Since we (per business requirement) cannot have an actual "submit"-button, I am no sure, without using `onChange`, how to track the changes in the form in order for us to auto trigger the auto-save function.

Comment: Sorry, I wasted your time. Here is the solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/9lkmwo61v4. Change the inputs and look at the Console.